# how to connect a device android to Local area network via VPN

Tags: vpn, lan, android

I want to connect my android phone to the local area network at company via VPN.

I use software "X-plore" to connect LAN via wifi is worked perfect.
But when i use 3G and use X-plore to connect LAN, it's dont work althougth i connected to VPN.
Please, tell me. How i can connect to LAN via VPN (or anything else)?

p/s: In IOS i use software "remote files" working perfect with VPN or no VPN.